# Saving to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner

I want to insert and edit values on the same button click.  The code is working fine and I am using the same code for both insertion and deletion.

```
function saveToDB(){
var value= pageValidation();
if($('#jobid').val()==" "){
    if(value!=false){
    var data = {        
        "names": $('#names').val(),
        "os": $('#OS').val(),
        "browser": $('#browsers').val(),
        "version": $('#version').val(),
        "scripttype": $('#testscripts').val(),
        "server": $('#server').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "/insertJobs",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("job insertion success");
            console.log(response);
            displayjobs();
        }
    });
  }
}
else{

    if(value!=false){
    var data = {
        "jobid": $('#jobid').val(),
        "names": $('#names').val(),
        "os": $('#OS').val(),
        "browser": $('#browsers').val(),
        "version": $('#version').val(),
        "scripttype": $('#testscripts').val(),
        "server": $('#server').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "/editJobs",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("job Updated succesfully!!");
            console.log(response);
            displayjobs();
        }
    });
  }
}
}
```

Are there any possible ways to remove duplication and compress this code?

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between the two code blocks is the service endpoint and the inclusion of the ID, so you could shorten it to:

```
function saveToDB(){
    var jobId = $('#jobid').val();      
    var valid = pageValidation();
    var url = jobId === " " ? "/insertJobs" : "/editJobs" ;

    if(valid){
        var data = {
            "jobid": jobId.trim(),        
            "names": $('#names').val(),
            "os": $('#OS').val(),
            "browser": $('#browsers').val(),
            "version": $('#version').val(),
            "scripttype": $('#testscripts').val(),
            "server": $('#server').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Change this message");
                console.log(response);
                displayjobs();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That code assumes that the code running at `/insertJobs` will ignore the empty `jobid` value.  If it won't, update the code so as not to send it.